Proper Apache2 server configuration on VPS with Python Ubuntu
Hello: I am trying to get my Python-Django website running on a VPS and I seem to be running into a problem that seems basic yet dated judging from all the google searches.  I wish to understand the concept as opposed to reacting to the individual error messages.
In creating my .conf file, I am running into either client denial or failure for my website to start up once I post the IP address.
I have a document root pointing to /var/www and a Directory pointing to the wsgi.py folder of the Django project with the WSGI script alias and Daemon processes detailed..  When I input the IP address, I see the index of files listed in the /var/www folder but there is no launch of the website.
If I modify the document root by pointing to the Django related folders, I either get:

No matching DirectoryIndex and server generated directory index forbidden
client refused by server configuration and I generate error log entries
i do not know if this has any bearing but I am also getting a server failure when I try a nslookup with my fQDN domain name, while a good result occurs with the IP address.

There are a lot of conflicting and dated recommendations made more difficult to rely upon given the flexibility of Apache.
Am I supposed to resolve the Django folder permissions/setups so that the WSGI functionality works or am I supposed to structure the /var/www files in some way?  I have a working Apache configuration with my Django website - I just cannot get the right final connection when I try to access the IP address (leaving alone the DNS issue).
Best regards and thanks
